# How can I import javax.xml.XPath if missing?

Tags: java, android, xpath

When I type: **import javax.xml.**

all that I have got available is:

javax.xml.parsers
javax.xml.XMLConstants

I need javax.xml.XPath
What do I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

It's [`javax.xml.xpath.XPath`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPath.html), try that instead.

Comment: all I get after .xml. is parsers or XMLConstants.

Comment: Check your project build path - this interface should be provided by the jre

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse and a Mac, add your objects (even if you use them statically) and then hit Cmd + Shift + O ( == Organize Imports ). Windows is Ctrl + Shift + O.  This will add any missing import statements.
If you are missing XPath, you can download the Jar from one of these sources:
[apache.org](http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/)
Or [download the latest stable build here](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/xalan/xalan/2.6.0/xalan-2.6.0.jar)

Comment: I know how to automatically add an import statement. I am using IntelliJ. I don't have a xpath available.